# Cannot access jira remolty

Tags: tomcat, jira

I had installed jia on my remote linux server as the following:

1-uploaded jira7.0.0.bin to my server.

2-logged in via ssh as root user

3-install jira as the instructions [here](https://confluence.atlassian.com/jira/installing-jira-on-linux-191501165.html)

4- I used the default configuration for port number 8080 and 8005.

when i tried to access it remotely as `https://myipaddress:8080`
 i always get connection time out.

How I can configure jira to allow remote access ?